# Help with jQuery .prepend() usage

Tags: jquery

`.prepend()` works when there is one line of code such as `.prepend("<li>item1<li>")` but when I try to put a big block of code in it, such as multiple divs with classes etc, it doesn't work. I did however, see that you can pass it a function but I can't figure out the syntax.

If I need to use `$(selector).prepend(function(index,html))` instead please help me use this.

Edit: I got it working by passing a function into it, I still don't understand how to use the index,html parameters.

Comment: Are you generating the string dynamically? Maybe you should create and prepend the elements individually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create string...

```
var myString = '<div class="lorem"><div id="temp" class="ipsum"></div></div>';
```

and then prepend it:

```
$(selector).prepend(myString);
```

Note: Always reduce DOM insertions to a minium. Working solution: http://jsfiddle.net/mCUWe/

EDIT: If you want to format your markup you're able to do something called string concatenation. Works as well: http://jsfiddle.net/mCUWe/1/

```
var myString = '<div class="lorem">LOREM'
              +'<div id="temp" class="ipsum">IPSUM'
              +'</div></div>';
```

**Update 02/2017**

Nowadays I recommended to go with [ES2015 Template-Strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: I think my issue was that there was multiple linebreaks and I wasn't using the "/".

Comment: Yes. Linebreaks will break your code... see my update above. Maybe for further projects. Just as sugesstion :)

Answer (score 1):

The `index` parameter will tell you the position of the current element in the selector

The `html` parameter will tell you the old html for the current element

For example, if you want have a `ul` and want to to insert the `li` number to the begging:

```
$('ul').find('li').prepend(function(index, html){
  return 'li number ' + index;
})
```